# Why is the Debian testing version of a package behind the stable version?

Tags: debian, version

Having 2 Debian installations - one on testing and the other on stable - on two different machines, I noticed that the version for **chromium** in testing is **47.0.2526.80-1~deb8u1** ([testing on debian package website](https://packages.debian.org/testing/web/chromium)) while the one in stable is **48.0.2564.116-1~deb8u1** ([stable on debian pakage website](https://packages.debian.org/stable/web/chromium)). So testing seems to be behind stable.

Because testing is supposed to have more recent versions of the same package, or at least the same version, why does this happen? Do I misunderstand something about testing distribution?

Edit: seems strange for testing to skip a version, and I have noticed the discrepancy for at least 24 hours. I would have expected that testing would have been updated in this time. Is someone messing/tampering with the package maybe?

Comment: Updates in stable are typically security updates. Debian generally prefers to backport security patches. However, in the case of Chromium this is very difficult. So, instead, in the case of security updates, the Debian maintainers update the entire package instead of trying to backport it. I'm not sure why they skipped testing here, but maybe it was urgent to get those security problems fixed.

Comment: @foyletrou: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](http://unix.stackexchange.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/158353/foyletrou and http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/158356/foyletrou.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Answer (score 2):

While there is some security support for `testing`, packages are not uploaded directly into testing except for high-priority packages, since doing so creates some problems. Instead, it is expected that security updates to through the normal "upload to unstable, wait for migration" process, although the upload may be given higher priority so that the "wait for migration" bit there doesn't take as long.

In contrast, security updates to stable *are* done by directly uploading to stable, since there is no alternate suite to upload to. Normally security fixes are backported; but in the case of browsers, an exception is (reluctantly) made and a new upstream is uploaded instead.

The result may indeed be that for a short time, a more recent version of the browser can be available in stable than in testing. This should never be for more than a few days, however.